# making web content semi transparent and more transparent upon click or hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to make my iframe invisible upon loading and visible when mouse is hovering over it, however I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone tell me what is it I am doing incorrectly?

```js
$(document).ready(

function makeVisible(){
    $(".video").hover(function(){
    $('.youtube').css("visibility", "visible");
   })
)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
<script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
<section class = "video">
  <p>This is my section</p>
  <iframe class = "youtube" hover="makeVisible()" width="700" height="397" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pMX5yyW5Qp0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
  </iframe>
</section>
```

Comment: Look at logs in the console sometimes. This one gives: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: Your `$(document).ready(` should be `$(document).ready(function(){})` also any reason you're using JS to do this instead of the CSS selectors like `:hover`?

Comment: Why not just use `:hover` in CSS?

Comment: Remove the `)` after the `youtube` line

Comment: css hover is match easier.. try that

Comment: I agree with Script47... modify the visibility in the CSS. so much cleaner. Also, why do you call a hover function from the HTML and then in that function call a jquery hover function?

Comment: I wanted to use js just to get use to js but I then used css in a js file -.-. where is the missing ) I'm not familar with js syntax?

Comment: Also, the logic is incorrect, to click you'd have to hover to it would automatically set the opacity to 1 when you hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for JS code here, you can use the `:hover` pseudo selector in JS to amend the `opacity` of an element, like this:

```css
iframe { opacity: 0.2; }
iframe:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class="video">
  <p>This is my section</p>
  <iframe class="youtube" width="700" height="397" src="https://stacksnippets.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
```

Note that I had to change the iframe URL to stacksnippets.com as it's sandboxed.

Comment: Damn it! Was making a fiddle, have my +1.

Comment: Much simpler.  I was convoluting this. Thanks fellas

Comment: Any reason why having the actual video there would cause it not to work? your code works perfect. when I apply this css to the iframe I get no change, any idea?

Comment: I even set the opacity to something crazy just to see if anything changes and nothing.

Comment: Is it possible to control speed of how it loads with css?

Comment: or is that only a js thing

Comment: [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions).

Answer (score 0):

I know how to change the transparency/opacity of something when you click on something using Javascript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
<script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class = "video">
  <p>This is my section</p>
  <iframe class = "youtube" onclick="makeVisible()" width="700" height="397" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pMX5yyW5Qp0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen  style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
  </iframe>
</section>
```

JavaScript.js:

```
function makeVisible(){
 var video = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube')
 video.style.opacity = "Your opacity here"
}
```